# How to find if a string and an array share matching values?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a string `s` which uses commas to separate list items. I also have an array of strings `Array`. I want to use LINQ to return `true` or `false` depending on whether on not the Array has any matching values in the string.

```
string s = "Onhold, Test,  Planned";
string[] Array = new string[] {"test34", "Planned"  };

var results = s.Split(',').Intersect(Array);
```

I'm not currently returning anything when I expect "Planned" to be returned.

Comment: Hint: look at the result of `s.Split(',')` in the debugger. It doesn't contain the string `"Planned"` - it contains the string `"  Planned"`

Comment: `s.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)`

Comment: @Charlieface: Nice, didn't know

Answer (score -1):

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        string s = "Onhold, Test,  Planned";
        string[] Array = new string[] { "test34", "Planned" };

        bool result = s.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).Intersect(Array).Any();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could add what you have done to fix it: trim each token. You should also show the code to return `bool`, if any items match(what was asked). As bonus you could add what OP needed to do to make it case insensitive